# Mips convert constant to ascii

Tags: mips

I need a code that having a constant (a number between 1 and 31 stored in memory) can add another constant (40) and convert the result in ascii (each number to the equivalent character in ascii).

I tried like this:

```
    .data 0x10010000
day: .byte 05
    .text 0x400000
main:   la $t0, day
        lw $t1, ($t0)
        addiu $t1, $t1, 40

end:
```

Now $t1=0x2d=45 decimal. How can I convert 0x2d to 0x3435?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I think you're already seeing it.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I don't know how to convert from decimal (as hex) to ascii.